# DRY Code: Use JQuery to make loop for a similar properties in function attached to different classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) to make slider. However on implementation. I realised I need to make different classes for the different blocks. The properties remain unchanged apart from the classes that differ. Can I get help on refactoring the code below. A loop that doesn't need ES6 but just ordinary Vanilla JS or jquery loops. I just need to refactor for DRY code

Newbie here. Thanks in advance.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery( '.mps-carousel' ).slick({
    accessibility: true,
    autoplay: true,
    dots: true,
    infinite: false,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 7,
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 1024,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 3,
          slidesToScroll: 3,
          infinite: true,
          dots: true
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 600,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 3,
          slidesToScroll: 3
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 480,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1
        }
      }
      // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
      // settings: "unslick"
      // instead of a settings object
    ]

  });

  jQuery('.uganda-carousel').slick({
    accessibility: true,
    autoplay: true,
    dots: true,
    infinite: false,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 7,
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 1024,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 3,
          slidesToScroll: 3,
          infinite: true,
          dots: true
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 600,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 3,
          slidesToScroll: 3
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 480,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1
        }
      }
      // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
      // settings: "unslick"
      // instead of a settings object
    ]

  });

  jQuery('.kenya-carousel').slick({
    accessibility: true,
    autoplay: true,
    dots: true,
    infinite: false,
    speed: 300,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 7,
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 1024,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 3,
          slidesToScroll: 3,
          infinite: true,
          dots: true
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 600,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 3,
          slidesToScroll: 3
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 480,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1
        }
      }
      // You can unslick at a given breakpoint now by adding:
      // settings: "unslick"
      // instead of a settings object
    ]

  });

});
```

Comment: use [Multiple Selector (“selector1, selector2, selectorN”)](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) i.e. `jQuery( '.mps-carousel, .uganda-carousel' ).slick({....})`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a loop. As all the initialisation parameters are the same you can just select the three elements and call `slick()` on them at the same time:

```
jQuery(function($){
  $('.mps-carousel, .uganda-carousel, .kenya-carousel').slick({
    // your options...
  });
});
```

Also note the use of the modified document.ready handler above, which provides an inner scope for the `$` variable, so you can freely use it within the handler function.

Comment: Thanks. I was making errors on the brackets. as below.

'.mps-carousel', '.uganda-carousel', '.kenya-carousel'

Comment: There's also implementing as a plugin, but that might be a bit advanced. Worth noting though.

Comment: @omukiguy no problem, glad to help

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, give any element you want to use `slick()` on a new class, like `.slick-carousel`. And then use:

```js
jQuery(function($){
  $('.slick-carousel').each(function() {
    $(this).slick({
      // ...options
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="mps-carousel slick-carousel"></div>

<div class="uganda-carousel slick-carousel"></div>

<div class="kenya-carousel slick-carousel"></div>
```

One advantage to this is you don't have to add new selectors if new carousels are added down the road. You just add the `slick-carousel` class to the new element.

This setup also makes it slightly easier, imo, to add carousel specific settings if needed. For example:

```
jQuery(function($){
  $('.slick-carousel').each(function() {
    var carousel = $(this);
    var slidesToShow = (carousel.hasClass('uganda-carousel') ? 7 : 3);

    carousel.slick({
      accessibility: true,
      autoplay: true,
      dots: true,
      infinite: false,
      speed: 300,
      slidesToShow: slidesToShow,
      slidesToScroll: 7,
      // ... more options
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Nice refactoring!